# How can i setState from api in fuction base?

Tags: reactjs

I got a errror when setState

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id_article, title, abstract, previewimage, content, category, tags, create_at, update_at, author, slug, state}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

this i set state with code below

```
const [ListArticle, setListArticle] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    getListArticle().then((response) => {
        setListArticle(response.data)
    })
})
```

this is response.data

```
[{
    "id_article": "2ceb0d4b-ee51-434c-b294-a72dd80991a6",
    "title": "Hi every one",
    "abstract": "xxxx",
    "previewimage": null,
    "content": "xxxx",
    "category": "http://ip/Category/1a243352-d088-4573-bc87-690b4d97cf62/",
    "tags": [
        "http://ip/Tags/5ccccd96-3dea-4e37-9b44-f1b5fbc20d42/"
    ],
    "create_at": "2021-03-13T22:00:30.982182Z",
    "update_at": "2021-03-13T22:00:30.982216Z",
    "author": "http://ip/UserBlog/1/",
    "slug": "xxx",
    "state": "Public"
},
 .....
 ...
]
```

how i can to solve this error. thankyou

Comment: Show your `return`

Comment: Error has more to do with what you are trying to render than what you update state to be. The error is saying you are directly rendering the objects of that array versus mapping the object properties to renderable JSX. Can you show us how you attempt to render that response data?